# How can I remove CRLF line terminators from wget'ed file?

Tags: bash, wget

I want to download a pastebin a raw file, and I tried:

```
wget http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LBVNiRXa -O somefile
```

My only problem is that the file arrives with CRLF line terminators.

Can I remove the line terminators with only one command line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `tr` to remove them:

```
wget http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LBVNiRXa -O- | tr -d '\r' >somefile
```

Comment: Million Thanks!! My head was about to explode, wasted almost an hour on this trivial issue!