# how to block ips from text file with iptables?

Tags: bash, 15.04, iptables, firewall

i have text file that have some black listed ips like this

```
 105.159.179.241
 109.128.60.28
 109.193.162.27
```

i have difficult time to block the ips one by one.

i want to block all ips in this text file at once how can i do that ?

i am using `iptables` to block the `ip` that way but i had to do them one by one , i wanted to block all of them at once

```
iptables -A INPUT -s  the ip to drop -j DROP
```

i tried something like this

```
INTEX="eth1"
# CHANGE THIS
badip=/root/badip.db
IPT=/sbin/iptables
# delete previous droplist (INPUT,OUTPUT,FORWARD)
$IPT -D INPUT -j droplist
$IPT -D OUTPUT -j droplist
$IPT -D FORWARD -j droplist
# [FLUSH OLD RULES]
$IPT -F droplist
# [DROP OLD CHAIN]
$IPT -X droplist
# [CREATE CHAIN]
$IPT -N droplist
/bin/egrep -v "^#|^$" $badip | while IFS= read -r ip
do
        $IPT -A droplist -i $INTEX -s $ip -j LOG --log-prefix " myBad IP BlockList  "
        $IPT -A droplist -i $INTEX -s $ip -j DROP
done < "$badip"
# Drop it
$IPT -I INPUT -j droplist
$IPT -I OUTPUT -j droplist
$IPT -I FORWARD -j droplist
```

but i got

```
' not found.4.21: host/network `105.159.179.241
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
```

my network interface

```
#first
auto eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address xx.xx.xx.xx
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 91.134.249.254
broadcast 91.134.249.227


#second
auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
address xx.xx.xx.xx
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway xx.xx.xx.xx
broadcast xx.xx.xx.xx


# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address xx.xx.xx.xx
        netmask 255.255.255.255
        post-up /sbin/ip route add xx.xx.xx.xx dev eth0
        post-up /sbin/ip route add default via xx.xx.xx.xx
        pre-down /sbin/ip route del default via xx.xx.xx.xx
        pre-down /sbin/ip route del xx.xx.xx.xx dev eth0
    dns-nameserver xx.xx.xx.xx
        dns-search ovh.net
```

after convert the files to dos format i got

```
: not foundk.sh: 6: ./masipblock.sh: iptables
: not foundk.sh: 7: ./masipblock.sh: iptables
: not foundk.sh: 8: ./masipblock.sh: iptables
: not foundk.sh: 10: ./masipblock.sh: iptables
: not foundk.sh: 12: ./masipblock.sh: iptables
: not foundk.sh: 14: ./masipblock.sh: iptables
./masipblock.sh: 19: ./masipblock.sh: Syntax error: "done" unexpected (expecting          "do")
```

i redo the dos format and now it raised only

```
./masipblock.sh: 1: ./masipblock.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

**i rewrit the script from begining thats how it looks now**

```
#DROP OLD CHAIN
$IPT -X droplist
#CREATE CHAIN
$IPT -N droplist/bin/egrep -v "^#|^$" $badip | while IFS= read -r ip
do
$IPT -A droplist -i $INTEX -s $ip -j LOG --log-prefix " myBad IP BlockList  "
$IPT -A droplist -i $INTEX -s $ip -j DROP
done < "$badip"
#Dropit
$IPT -I INPUT -j droplist
$IPT -I OUTPUT -j droplist
$IPT -I FORWARD -j droplist
```

The od

```
0000000   I   N   T   E   X   =   "   e   t   h   0   "  \r   #       C
0000020   H   A   N   G   E       T   H   I   S  \r   b   a   d   i   p
0000040   =   /   r   o   o   t   /   b   a   d   i   p   .   d   b  \r
0000060   I   P   T   =   /   s   b   i   n   /   i   p   t   a   b   l
0000100   e   s  \r   #       d   e   l   e   t   e       p   r   e   v
0000120   i   o   u   s       d   r   o   p   l   i   s   t       (   I
0000140   N   P   U   T   ,   O   U   T   P   U   T   ,   F   O   R   W
0000160   A   R   D   )  \r   $   I   P   T       -   D       I   N   P
0000200   U   T       -   j       d   r   o   p   l   i   s   t  \r   $
0000220   I   P   T       -   D       O   U   T   P   U   T       -   j
0000240       d   r   o   p   l   i   s   t  \r   $   I   P   T       -
0000260   D       F   O   R   W   A   R   D       -   j       d   r   o
0000300   p   l   i   s   t  \r   #       [   F   L   U   S   H       O
0000320   L   D       R   U   L   E   S   ]  \r   $   I   P   T       -
0000340   F       d   r   o   p   l   i   s   t  \r   #       [   D   R
0000360   O   P       O   L   D       C   H   A   I   N   ]  \r   $   I
0000400   P   T       -   X       d   r   o   p   l   i   s   t  \r   #
0000420       [   C   R   E   A   T   E       C   H   A   I   N   ]  \r
0000440   $   I   P   T       -   N       d   r   o   p   l   i   s   t
0000460  \r   /   b   i   n   /   e   g   r   e   p       -   v       "
0000500   ^   #   |   ^   $   "       $   b   a   d   i   p       |
0000520   w   h   i   l   e       I   F   S   =       r   e   a   d
0000540   -   r       i   p  \r   d   o  \r
0000560       $   I   P   T       -   A       d   r   o   p   l   i   s
0000600   t       -   i       $   I   N   T   E   X       -   s       $
0000620   i   p       -   j       L   O   G       -   -   l   o   g   -
0000640   p   r   e   f   i   x       "       m   y   B   a   d       I
0000660   P       B   l   o   c   k   L   i   s   t           "  \r
0000700                               $   I   P   T       -   A       d
0000720   r   o   p   l   i   s   t       -   i       $   I   N   T   E
0000740   X       -   s       $   i   p       -   j       D   R   O   P
0000760  \r   d   o   n   e       <       "   $   b   a   d   i   p   "
0001000  \r   #       D   r   o   p       i   t  \r   $   I   P   T
0001020   -   I       I   N   P   U   T       -   j       d   r   o   p
0001040   l   i   s   t  \r   $   I   P   T       -   I       O   U   T
0001060   P   U   T       -   j       d   r   o   p   l   i   s   t  \r
0001100   $   I   P   T       -   I       F   O   R   W   A   R   D
0001120   -   j       d   r   o   p   l   i   s   t  \r
```

i used nano as editor 
i got **./masipblock.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
'IPT -I FORWARD -j droplist $INTEX -s $ip -j DROP--log-prefix " myBad IP BlockList  "**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44386/discussion-on-question-by-vlark-lopin-how-to-block-ips-from-text-file-with-iptab).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102703/8747573

Answer (score 0):

There is your problem:

0000060   b  \r  \n   I   P   T   =   /   s   b   i   n   /   i   p   t

0000100   a   b   l   e   s  `\r`  \n   #       d   e   l   e   t   e

that `\r` is confusing your shell.

Try a different text editor or use something similar to [How can I remove CRLF line terminators from wget'ed file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406899/how-can-i-remove-crlf-line-terminators-from-wgeted-file) to fix your problem, i.e.;

```
cat masipblock.sh | tr -d '\r' > masipblock2.sh
chmod +x masipblock2.sh
./masipblock2.sh
```

Comment: i am using nano what could i use instead as editor ?

Comment: in nano i used alt + m and alt + D and i got ./masipblock2.sh: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file